# What is the `unit` setting used for in ElasticSearch's geo distance sort?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, geocoding

In the [documentation it says](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#geo-sorting):

> unit
>   The unit to use when computing sort values. The default is m (meters).

**How is the unit setting used? Is the sorting process affected by the unit chosen?** For example, if I set it to miles (`mi`) would I get a less granular sort than if I used meters (`m`)? I don't need the distance value for each record in the results, so it does not matter to me which unit is used, unless it does affect the accuracy of the sort.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#geo-sorting

Answer (score -1):

The sort is apply after the unit conversion. Lucene, makeDistanceValueSource return the distance in the desired units (KM, Yard...) and the sort if apply after that.

Also note the accurate is so high, i am really not sure changing units could affect the sort order ;)

Comment: So if the sort is applied after the unit conversion, does that mean it is affected by the unit chosen? And if not, why isn't the sort applied prior to unit conversion then?

Comment: The lucene function calculate the distance (the units doesnot affect), and return it as a "score"  after that the sort is apply using this value, this is the value you got in the response (sort part) when you apply a geodistance sort.